# Encoding Problem: Atom can't print UTF-8 ('ä ö ü')

Tags: python, encoding, atom-editor

I got a new machine and after setting everything up, the IDE Atom somehow can't print the UTF-8 characters 'ä ö ü' anymore (other such characters probably as well).
It is super strange and I have this problem since moving to this new PC of mine.

**Here is a screenshot of the problem:**

[image: Screenshot]

**I'm using:**

- Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit
- Python 3.7.4 via Anaconda 1.9.7
- Atom 1.44.0
- platformio-ide-terminal 2.10.0 (as a terminal inside Atom)
- the system-wide environment variable: PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

**Did anybody encounter this problem as well and knows how to fix it?**

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT with solution**

**Solution 1:**
snakecharmerb (the user on here) commented, that I need to declair the encoding when opening the file 'test.py' with the following command:

```
open('test.py', encoding='utf-8')
```

That worked!
His/her comment was removed for some reason, but yeah, it worked. Thank you!

**Solution 2**:
In order to not have to declare the encoding every time, I looked into changing the systems default encoding. Windows 10 has an easy but kind of hidden solution for that:

[image: Use UTF-8]

Open Control panel >> Clock and Region >> Region >> Administrative tab >> Change system locale... >> checkmark 'Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support'

**Thanks for the amazingly fast help everyone!**

Comment: You'll probably want to report this over at the terminal plugin's issue tracker. https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal/issues

Comment: The output you see is UTF-8 but the terminal is displaying it in some godforsaken Windows code page.

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question; post an answer of your own if you like (even accept your own answer if you like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try exporting `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

if that doesn't work you can try setting your environment variables in python to

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I got it to work in two different ways due to your help and somebody elses (who for some reason removed his/her comment). I'll edit my question with the solutions in a minute. 

I have a follow up question though since I don't quite grasp what you meant by exporting PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 and setting the environment variable 'in python'. 

Can you elaboralte a little bit on how to do that?